# Callback to get results from geocoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, google-geocoder

I have a function, `getLatLong()` that I use throughout my code. I want it to return the latitude and longitude from a given address.

```
function getLatLong(address) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'region': 'uk' }, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

         lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(); 
         lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
         return [lat, lng];

     } else {
         return ("Unable to find address: " + status);
     }
});
```

}

Wanting to be able to do `getLatLong("London SW1A 1AA");` I seem to not be able to get it to work. It constantly returns `undefined`. After researching a bit, I see that I have to use a callback, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to stick with Google Geocoding API? You could try the HTML5 Geolocation API using this MDN [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). This API is very new and so be sure to check out the browser compatibility at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: Sadly, that wouldn't work since I have multiple different adresses I need to convert to Lat and Lng.

Comment: In case you haven't realized yet, you have used a callback in your code. the anon func within your geocode() method is the callback function. It returns either an array or a string. So store that in a var like var result = getLatLong() and check type of var using typeof and then handle if its an array or a string. By the way, the else part inside your anon func shouldn't be returning the string like return ("..."+str) but instead return ""+str; Hope this helps.